# Using memorystream to make a pdf download using VB.NET and Webforms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I have a method that I wrote that calls a ReportServer and returns a byte array of a pdf of the report. This works. I know because I've used the same method to write a pdf to a file and save it locally. Here I want to write the file to a memory stream and offer it as a download.

```
    Try
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(report, 0, report.Length)
        ms.Position = 0

        Response.Clear()
        Response.Expires = 0
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserReport.pdf")
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        'ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray())
        Response.End()
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
        'Response.Flush()

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblERRORMSG.Visible = True
        lblERRORMSG.Text = "Darn!" & ex.Message
        Return
    End Try
End Sub`
```

This code compiles, runs, and I can even set breakpoints that get hit. But when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` will never get hit. `Response.End()` throws a `ThreadAbortException` by design.

Comment: I've seen that Response.End() throws an exception but the message is an empty string so I want to keep that code to catch any other exceptions, I think.

Comment: You should move Response.End outside the try/catch. And ditch CompleteRequest.

Comment: Still not giving me the download.  I also got rid of the return in the Catch... I thought it would cause the Response.End() to get skipped over.

Comment: Use your browser's debug tools to inspect the network traffic. What happens there when you try to download?

Comment: Here's what the debugger looks like on the network after I click the button.
http://imgur.com/YB8C6mZ

Comment: So look at the response and see what it looks like.

Comment: I agree with @mason move `Response.End()` I tested this code by passing in an array of bytes (from reading a pdf) as the value for report and it works. If there is a problem it may be with the value of report??

Comment: Got it figured out thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code in question. This code was being used with an UpdatePanel made by telerik called a RadAjaxPanel. The default setting for buttons on pages that use this control is that **they do NOT post back.** The solution was simple. You need to go to the Page_Load Event in you code behind and add the following code:

`ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(btnNameGoesHere)`

This will trigger a postback when the button is clicked!